# In fact, Indeed

Tags: phrases, synonyms

Jair Bolsonaro is the new president of Brazil. Indeed, this last election provoked a division of opinions among voters.

In this phrase is normal use "in fact" or "indeed"? These words are synonymous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Definition of *in fact*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_(point_of)_fact)

[Definition of *indeed*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indeed)

Neither are applicable here, in my opinion. They are used for emphasising or countering a point. The sentence **"Jair Bolsonaro is the new president of Brazil"** has no mention or implication of how divided the voters are. Best just to leave them out.

> Jair Bolsonaro is the new president of Brazil. This last election provoked a division of opinions among voters.

Comment: Thanks Omegastick. Could you give me an example of using these expressions? What the diference between both?

Comment: In fact: **"A lot of people say Keanu Reeves is a great actor, but I'm not sure I agree. In fact, I find him quite dull."** No offense intended to Mr Reeves. Indeed: **"Do you think Keanu Reeves is a good actor?" "Oh, I do indeed."**